# can't find documents by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I'm trying to update a document but it just doesn't work with _id but if I filter with "name" it works
I also tried with FindByID and it returns null
using mongoose version 5.0.18

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises')
    .then(() => console.log('connected to database :)'))
    .catch(reason => console.log('Can not connect to data base',reason));

const courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    Date: { type:Date,default:Date.now },
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number
});
const Course = mongoose.model('courses',courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id){
  let result = await Course.update({_id: id},{
      $set:{
          author: "some random dude",
          isPublished: true
      }
  });

  console.log('result: ',result);

}

updateCourse('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e');
```

Comment: Change Course.findByIdAndUpdate(id) by Course.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id) ???

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
//make sure you import Course module

Course.findByIdAndUpdate(id)
.then(response=>{

})
.catch(err=>{

})
```

Comment: well it returns Null

Answer (score 0):

I just had to re-import the collection without _id so it can regenerate them